# Export friend operator from template class

Tags: c++, templates, dll, friend

Is there a way to export a friend operator defined in a template class?

**matrix.hpp**

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    // Some members...

public:
    // Some functions...
    
    Matrix operator+(const T&) const;
    friend Matrix operator+(const T&, const Matrix&);
};
```

**matrix.cpp**

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const T& rhs) const
{
    // Addition of a matrix with object T...
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const T& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs)
{
    return rhs + lhs; // Defined above
}

template __declspec(dllexport) Matrix<int> Matrix<int>::operator+(const int&) const; // This WORKS

template __declspec(dllexport) Matrix<int> operator+(const int& lhs, const Matrix<int>& rhs); // This DOESN'T COMPILE
// Compiler shows error E0801: "operator+" is not a class or function template name in the current scope
```

So in my executable I can do a `Matrix<int> a = matrix + 10;` but not `Matrix<int> a = 10 + matrix;`, bit frustrating...

Comment: Friends of templates aren't templates themselves. Suggestion:  `friend Matrix operator+(const T& t, const Matrix& m ) { return m + t; }` - reuse the operator you *can* hide.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica care to write a proper answer for this or I should go ahead?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - Well, I'm 99% certain there's a duplicate somewhere. You can help look for it if you'd like. Or answer. Either way, I think closure is appropriate.

Comment: Ultimately, my comment basically re-iterates option 3 in the accepted answer on the duplicate. Use a member function in an inline friend definition..

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica thanks for clarifying why no answer has been written yet.